# Create jpeg image from imageView.image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am working on an app where the user has to register. In this process, you can choose a profile image. The process is like this: You tap on the `imageView`, the `imagePicker` opens (you can select from camera or gallery) and after you choose an image, the `picker` closes and the image is loaded into the `imageview`. Now the question is, how can I create an jpeg from the `imageView.image`, so that i can upload it via `Alamofire` to the backend?

here the Code:

When Image is selected via picker:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        //previewImage is the imageView where the image is displayed
        previewImage.image = pickedImage
        previewImage.layer.cornerRadius = 55
        profileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.isHidden = true
    

        UserData.shared.profilePicture = previewImage.image!
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And here the method which uploads the image:

```
    func uploadImage(profileImage: UIImage) {
    
    let image = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("profile.jpeg")
    try? image!.write(to: filename)
    
    
    AF.request(Constants.uploadProfileUrl, method: .post, parameters: ["profile": UIImage(named: "profile")], headers: ["Content-Type":"multipart/form-data", "Authorization": "Bearer "+Configuration.accessToken]) { urlRequest in
    }.response { response in
        print(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.successfulRegister, sender: self)
        case .failure(let error):
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            print(statusCode)
            print("fail")
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow I get an success message from `alamofire` but the image is not shown in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

try it :-

- take a global variable for UIImage
- store the picked image in that variable
- send that  image in alamofire (compress if needed)

```
let image = UIImage()

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        self.image = pickedImage
        previewImage.image = pickedImage
        previewImage.layer.cornerRadius = 55
        profileView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.isHidden = true
    

        UserData.shared.profilePicture = previewImage.image!
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```